# Django Rest Framework - Return no values if filter is not selected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a fairly simple view where, if no filters are selected, I want the api call to return nothing.  Currently the base api url returns everything and the filters successfully limit the return which is half way to what I want.

so this would return values:

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/widgets/?name=abc&list=def

this would return no results:

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/widgets/

Here is my current view:

```
class WidgetViewSet(EncryptedLookupGenericViewSet,
                      viewsets.ModelViewSet,
                      ):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ]
    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_class = WidgetFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(WidgetViewSet, self).get_queryset().filter(list__owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if `request.GET` is empty

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.GET:
        return super(WidgetViewSet, self).get_queryset().filter(list__owner=self.request.user)
    else:
        return self.queryset.none()
```